# Is it possible to iterate over two IEnumerable objects at the same time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

If I have a List(Of x) and a List(Of y) is it possible to iterate over both at the same time?

Something like

```
for each _x as X, _y as Y in List(of x), List(of y) 
    if _x.item = _y.item then
        'do something
    end if
next
```

These lists may be of differing sizes.

I am using .Net2.0 which I suspect is my downfall here as I have a feeling LINQ would solve something like easily by joining the lists on there common id.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right; LINQ would save you a ton of hassle.

Push for an upgrade! .NET 3.5 and .NET 2.0 play well together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC, .Net 4.0 will have a `.Zip()` extension method for IEnumerable that already does this.

In the meantime, it's not that hard to build your own.  Surprisingly, while several other answers were very close they all have a least one problem.  Hopefully they will be corrected.  In the meantime, this should do what you want it to, in VB.Net, with strongly-typed enumerators, using a correct comparison for the unknown types, and correctly dispose of the enumerators:

```vb
Using xe As IEnumerator(Of X) = List1.GetEnumerator()
Using ye As IEnumerator(Of Y) = List2.GetEnumerator()

    While xe.MoveNext() AndAlso ye.MoveNext() 
        If xe.Current.Equals(ye.Current) Then
            ' do something
        End If
    End While
End Using
End Using
```

And now let's put this into a function you can pass your own delegates to:

```vb
Public Shared Sub ZipAction(Of X, Y)(ByVal source1 As IEnumerable(Of X), ByVal source2 As IEnumerable(Of Y), _
                              ByVal compare As Func(Of X, Y, Boolean), Byval OnEquals As Action(Of X, Y))  

    Using xe As IEnumerator(Of X) = source1.GetEnumerator()
    Using ye As IEnumerator(Of Y) = source2.GetEnumerator()
    
        While xe.MoveNext() AndAlso ye.MoveNext() 
            If compare(xe.Current, ye.Current) Then
                OnEquals(xe.Current, ye.Current)
            End If
        End While
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

And finally, since those delegate types aren't available until .Net 3.5 you can easily declare them in .Net 2.0 like this:

```vb
Public Delegate Sub Action(Of T1, T2) ( _
    arg1 As T1, _
    arg2 As T2 _
)

Public Delegate Function Func(Of T1, T2, TResult) ( _
    arg1 As T1, _
    arg2 As T2, _
) As TResult
```

To use this code, you'd do something like this:

```vb
Public Class X
    Public Item As String
    ' ...
End Class

Public Class Y
    Public Item As String
    ' ...
End Class

Public Class Test

    Private Function CompareXtoY(ByVal arg1 As X, ByVal arg2 As Y) As Boolean
        Return arg1.Item = arg2.Item
    End Function

    Private Sub OnList1ItemMatchesList2Item(ByVal arg1 As X, ByVal arg2 As Y)
        ' Do something...
    End Sub

    Private list1 As List(Of X) = GetXList()
    Private list2 As List(Of Y) = GetYList()

    Public Sub TestZip()
        ZipAction(list1, list2, AddressOf CompareXtoY, AddressOf OnList1ItemMatchesList2Item)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If this were C#, I would have the function be an iterator block and "yield return" each matching pair rather than asking you to pass in an Action delegate.

Comment: He did mention that the lists may be of differing sizes. I believe in your example it would just stop as soon as one of them reaches it's end. So Ha! my way is better :-P

Comment: If the lists are different sizes, the items left over in the longer list will not match anything in the shorter list and so nothing would happen anyway.

Comment: Assuming inner-join is probably safer than assuming outer-join.

Comment: Eh: there's something to be said for outer join. In C# 3.0, BFree's code makes a lot of sense because you can just put a .Where() on the end of his very generic function (or even just call .Intersect() in the first place).  In VB.Net for .Net 2.0 we can't build iterator blocks or extensions and so I think the more-specific 'inner join' approach makes more sense here.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an old-fashioned for loop. Something like

```
For ii As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count)
    If list1(ii) = list2(ii) Then
    End If
Next
```

Comment: i like this answer, its clever.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this does not work for IEnumerable because IEnumerable does not define () or .Count

Comment: But list does, and the OP specified lists.

Answer (score 2):

No, not in vb.net with the vb loop constructs.

You can however do it yourself with the enumerators:

```
    Sub MyOwnIENumeration()
    Dim a As List(Of String), b As List(Of String)
    Dim EnmA As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of String) = a.GetEnumerator
    Dim EnmB As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of String) = b.GetEnumerator

    If EnmA.MoveNext() And EnmB.MoveNext() Then
        Do
            If EnmA.Current = EnmB.Current Then
                Debug.Print("list matched on " & EnmA.Current)
                If Not EnmA.MoveNext() Then Exit Do
                If Not EnmB.MoveNext() Then Exit Do
            ElseIf EnmA.Current < EnmB.Current Then
                If Not EnmA.MoveNext() Then Exit Do
            Else
                If Not EnmB.MoveNext() Then Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    EnmA.Dispose() : EnmB.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to access the enumerators manually. In C#:

```
using (IEnumerator<X> xe = List1.GetEnumerator())
using (IEnumerator<Y> ye = List2.GetEnumerator()) {
    while (xe.MoveNext() && ye.MoveNext()) {
         if (xe.Current == ye.Current) {
             // do something
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean without doing a nested loop?

```
foreach _x as X in List(of x)
     foreach _y as Y in List(of y)
          if _x.item = _y.item then
               'do something
          end if
 next
```

Not a VB programmer so my syntax might be wrong but you get the idea.

Comment: It's not the syntax: it's that it will re-iterate every item in Y for every item in X.  It's O(n^2) rather than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very proficient in VB.NET, but here's an extension method in C# you can create to do this. I hope you can port it!

```
public static class IEnumExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, U>> EnumTwoCollections<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<U> list2)
    {
        var enumerator1 = list1.GetEnumerator();
        var enumerator2 = list2.GetEnumerator();

        bool moveNext1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        bool moveNext2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

        while (moveNext1 || moveNext2)
        {

            T tItem = moveNext1 ? enumerator1.Current : default(T);
            U uItem = moveNext2 ? enumerator2.Current : default(U);

            yield return new KeyValuePair<T, U>(tItem, uItem);

            moveNext1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
            moveNext2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        intList.Add(i);
        stringList.Add((i * i).ToString());
    }

    foreach (var items in intList.EnumTwoCollections(stringList))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items.Key + " , " + items.Value);
    }
```

Noticed now that you're not using .NET 3.5 so you probably can't use extension methods either. Just put this in some helper class and you can call it like this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,string> kvp in Helper.EnumTwoCollections(intList,stringList))
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the GetEnumerator() function of each IEnumerable.

You could do something like:

```
 // Assume List1 and List2 are IEnumerable variables
 Dim list1 As IEnumerator = List1.GetEnumerator()
 Dim list2 As IEnumerator = List2.GetEnumerator();
 While list1.MoveNext() And list2.MoveNext()
      If list1.Current = list2.Current Then
          // Do Something
      End If
 End While
```

Here is some more info from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48zfb676.aspx)

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use CompareTo to test for equality - more information is at http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/30/every-problem-looks-like-a-nail.aspx

Comment: Getting closer, but you still need to remember to dispose of the enumerables.

Comment: Also, I see no reason for do/while construct.  IT's possible to have empty lists, you know.

Comment: I just checked and IEnumerator<T> implements IDisposable but IEnumerator does not.  So do you dispose of it just by setting it null since there's not Dispose() method?

Comment: I didn't realize IEnumerator was not an IDisposable.  In that case you're okay there, but the other two complaints still stand (and fixing the last one makes this an issue again).

Comment: The logic is still sound.  He now has a basis for implementing it in his own circumstances.