# How to iterate through two IEnumerables simultaneously?

Tags: c#, iteration, ienumerable

I have two enumerables: `IEnumerable<A> list1` and `IEnumerable<B> list2`. I would like to iterate through them simultaneously like:

```
foreach((a, b) in (list1, list2))
{
    // use a and b
}
```

If they don't contain the same number of elements, an exception should be thrown.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Answers for Java, too, please.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981867/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-two-ienumerable-objects-at-the-same-time ?

Comment: @Thilo - ask a separate question for that as the answer is likely to be very different. Don't forget to search first in case it's already been asked.

Comment: Why not just compare the counts to throw the exception, then otherwise handle it with a for loop and counter? it's the easiest way to enforce using a[counter] with b[counter] and knowing that your code does what you intend. "Law of unintended consequences" ;)

Comment: @drachenstern You can't use a for loop or know the count of an IEnumerable (at least, not without first traversing the whole thing), as it's not a list. It's possible his enumerables are expensive to enumerate, so he just wants to do it once.

Comment: @Jean: This is not a duplicate. It is neither about VB nor about List.

Comment: @Danvil - the VB and C# solutions will be equivalent, and `List` implements `IEnumerable` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) so the same answer will apply.

Comment: @ChrisF - Since List implements IEnumerable, if the OP had asked for a List solution, and an IEnumerable solution were supplied, then that would be applicable. However, the converse is not true. IEnumerable (as in the OP) does not implement List.

Comment: @Matt - doh, had List on me mind... where's my caffeine?

Comment: @Jeffrey - You're right. My mistake. I was pointing out that the VB and C# solutions would be equivalent and got carried away.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's an implementation of this operation, typically called Zip:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO2721939
{
    public sealed class ZipEntry<T1, T2>
    {
        public ZipEntry(int index, T1 value1, T2 value2)
        {
            Index = index;
            Value1 = value1;
            Value2 = value2;
        }

        public int Index { get; private set; }
        public T1 Value1 { get; private set; }
        public T2 Value2 { get; private set; }
    }

    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ZipEntry<T1, T2>> Zip<T1, T2>(
            this IEnumerable<T1> collection1, IEnumerable<T2> collection2)
        {
            if (collection1 == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("collection1");
            if (collection2 == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("collection2");

            int index = 0;
            using (IEnumerator<T1> enumerator1 = collection1.GetEnumerator())
            using (IEnumerator<T2> enumerator2 = collection2.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator1.MoveNext() && enumerator2.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return new ZipEntry<T1, T2>(
                        index, enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            string[] names = new[] { "Bob", "Alice", "Mark", "John", "Mary" };

            foreach (var entry in numbers.Zip(names))
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(entry.Index + ": "
                    + entry.Value1 + "-" + entry.Value2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make it throw an exception if just one of the sequences run out of values, change the while-loop so:

```
while (true)
{
    bool hasNext1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
    bool hasNext2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
    if (hasNext1 != hasNext2)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("One of the collections ran " +
            "out of values before the other");
    if (!hasNext1)
        break;

    yield return new ZipEntry<T1, T2>(
        index, enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of this Zip algorithm used before, what type of problem does this solve? Seeing as it's directly supported in 4.0 clearly it's a very well known problem even if I've never had a need for it myself.

Comment: It allows you to enumerate over two collections side-by-side. You can each chain them, `a.Zip(b).Zip(c)`, but it'll give you x.Value1.Value1, x.Value1.Value2 and x.Value2. Think of the name, a "zipper", like in pants.

Answer (score 58):

You want something like the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(VS.100).aspx) LINQ operator - but the version in .NET 4 always just truncates when either sequence finishes.

The [MoreLINQ implementation](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/EquiZip.cs) has an `EquiZip` method which will throw an `InvalidOperationException` instead.

```
var zipped = list1.EquiZip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b });

foreach (var element in zipped)
{
    // use element.a and element.b
}
```

Comment: Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0

Comment: The MoreLINQ source was moved to [Github](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/EquiZip.cs).

Comment: @bdrajer: Do feel free to edit posts yourself in future to make links work... will fix it now.

Answer (score 22):

In short, the language offers no clean way to do this. Enumeration was designed to be done over one enumerable at a time. You can mimic what foreach does for you pretty easily:

```
using(IEnumerator<A> list1enum = list1.GetEnumerator())
using(IEnumerator<B> list2enum = list2.GetEnumerator())    
while(list1enum.MoveNext() && list2enum.MoveNext()) {
        // list1enum.Current and list2enum.Current point to each current item
    }
```

What to do if they are of different length is up to you. Perhaps find out which one still has elements after the while loop is done and keep working with that one, throw an exception if they should be the same length, etc.

Answer (score 8):

In .NET 4, you can use the .Zip extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`

```
IEnumerable<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 100);
IEnumerable<int> list2 = Enumerable.Range(100, 100);

foreach (var item in list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new { a, b }))
{
    // use item.a and item.b
}
```

It won't throw on unequal lengths, however. You can always test that, though.

Answer (score 3):

Go with IEnumerable.GetEnumerator, so you can move around the enumerable. Note that this might have some really nasty behavior, and you must be careful. If you want to get it working, go with this, if you want to have maintainable code, use two foreach.

You could create a wrapping class or use a library (as Jon Skeet suggests) to handle this functionality in a more generic way if you are going to use it more than once thru your code.

The code for what I suggest:

```
var firstEnum = aIEnumerable.GetEnumerator();
var secondEnum = bIEnumerable.GetEnumerator();

var firstEnumMoreItems = firstEnum.MoveNext();
var secondEnumMoreItems = secondEnum.MoveNext();    

while (firstEnumMoreItems && secondEnumMoreItems)
{
      // Do whatever.  
      firstEnumMoreItems = firstEnum.MoveNext();
      secondEnumMoreItems = secondEnum.MoveNext();   
}

if (firstEnumMoreItems || secondEnumMoreItems)
{
     Throw new Exception("One Enum is bigger");
}

// IEnumerator does not have a Dispose method, but IEnumerator<T> has.
if (firstEnum is IDisposable) { ((IDisposable)firstEnum).Dispose(); }
if (secondEnum is IDisposable) { ((IDisposable)secondEnum).Dispose(); }
```

Comment: I think this contains a subtle bug. If firstEnum contains one more item than secondEnum, then no exception will be thrown.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the enumerators. And NEVER EVER EVER call Reset. In most enumerators it throws an exception. Reset was included for compatibility with COM enumerators.

Comment: Note that you have to say "if (first is IDisposable)  ((IDisposable)first).Dispose();

Comment: By changing "&&" to "&" it will now fail to throw an error if either collection contains one more item than the other. The problem is that the return value of MoveNext is being used in two places to do two things, but each call to MoveNext potentially changes its value. This is why the other solutions cache the value returned from MoveNext, even though it looks like a wordy, useless temp variable.

Comment: Changed, @Eric I don't think casting is necessary.

Comment: @jpabluz: Well, I think it is necessary in the following circumstances: (1) the compile-time type of GetEnumerator is IEnumerator, (2) the compile-time type of GetEnumerator is a type which does not implement IDisposable, or (3) the compile-time type of GetEnumerator is a type which explicitly implements IDisposable.

Comment: @jpabluz: first: you would rather *start the compiler again at runtime* than insert a cast? Note that by making those dynamic you have made *every single operation in this program fragment dynamic also.* Second **that doesn't work either**. Dynamic will not dispatch explicit implementations. I've described how to write the code correctly several times now; why are you resisting doing it correctly?

Comment: Every change I do, is making me more knowledgeable, which its why I am here in the first place. So I have to thank you. =)

Answer (score 3):

```
using(var enum1 = list1.GetEnumerator())
using(var enum2 = list2.GetEnumerator())
{
    while(true)
    {
        bool moveNext1 = enum1.MoveNext();
        bool moveNext2 = enum2.MoveNext();
        if (moveNext1 != moveNext2)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (!moveNext1)
            break;
        var a = enum1.Current;
        var b = enum2.Current;
        // use a and b
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose your enumerators.

Comment: Will this throw if list2 has more items than list1?

Comment: @drachenstern - I think so. In that case moveNext1 will be false and moveNext2 will be true. Since those values are not equal, it will throw the exception.

Comment: Oh good lord, I can't read this morning... It's a wonder I'm getting any code written today at all... (well, actually that would explain a few things, such as my total LoC contribution this morning has been about 6...) ~ Can I just goto bed and try again tomorrow?

Comment: Raising the dead here, but should those last lines of code be `var a = enum1.Current`? etc

Comment: @PeterM - Indeed, you're right. I must have been having just as bad a day as jcolebrand that day.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Zip` function like

```
foreach (var entry in list1.Zip(list2, (a,b)=>new {First=a, Second=b}) {
    // use entry.First und entry.Second
}
```

This doesn't throw an exception, though ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
IEnumerator enuma = a.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator enumb = b.GetEnumerator();
while (enuma.MoveNext() && enumb.MoveNext())
{
    string vala = enuma.Current as string;
    string valb = enumb.Current as string;
}
```

C# has no foreach that can do it how you want (that I am aware of).

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the enumerators.

Comment: IEnumerator is not disposable.  You are thinking of the generic version IEnumerator<T> which is disposable.  The above is valid.

Comment: But 99% of the `IEnumerator` instances you encounter in the wild are going to be `IEnumerator<T>` instances with `IEnumerator` implemented for backwards compatibility.  The use case the OP is proposing seems to call for lazily computed `IEnumerable<T>` instances, so the code should call the `.Dispose()` methods of the objects returned by `a.GetEnumerator()` and `b.GetEnumerator()` if they actually implement `IDisposable`.  Or just do it with generics, so you can just use a `using` block and get type-safety as a bonus.

Comment: Exactly. The necessity of disposing an object that implements IDisposable does not magically disappear when you look at it as an IEnumerator!

Answer (score 1):

Since C# 7.0 introduced tuples, you can create a generic `Lockstep` function that returns an `IEnumerable<(T1, T2)>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T1, T2)> Lockstep<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> t1s, IEnumerable<T2> t2s)
{
    using IEnumerator<T1> enum1 = t1s.GetEnumerator();
    using IEnumerator<T2> enum2 = t2s.GetEnumerator();
    while (enum1.MoveNext() && enum2.MoveNext())
        yield return (enum1.Current, enum2.Current);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
void LockstepDemo(IEnumerable<A> xs, IEnumerable<B> ys)
{
    foreach (var (x, y) in Lockstep(xs, ys))
        Consume(x, y);
}
```

If you need three or more enumerations, you can overload `Lockstep` with three or more parameters.