# Iterating through two lists simultaneously

Tags: c#, iteration

I'm doing this.

```
List<Type1> t1 = ...
List<Type2> t2 = ...
List<Type3> t3 = new List<Type3>();

for(int i = 0; i < t1.Count; i++)
  t3.AddRange(new Type3(t1[i], t2[i]));
```

I've tried to use `foreach` by deploying this.

```
IEnumerable<Type1> t1 = ...
IEnumerable<Type2> t2 = ...
IEnumerable<Object> t12 = t1.Zip(t2, (outer, inner)
  => new{ Outer = outer, Inner = inner});
List<Type3> t3 = new List<Type3>();

foreach(Object element in t12)
  t3.Add(new Type3(element.Outer, element.Inner));
```

This doesn't fly because `Object` doesn't recognize the `Outer` and `Inner` properties. I can't `as` it either, because it's a anonymous type. What can I do?

I'd also prefer not to use `Object` or `var` but a `Tuple` or something that says "it's a `<Type1,Type2>` combo kind of thing".

*NB. There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721939/how-to-iterate-through-two-ienumerables-simultaneously) discussion but that doesn't really answer my question. And in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955766/iterate-two-lists-or-arrays-with-one-foreach-statment-in-c-sharp) I just can't get the fields.*

Comment: What's so wrong with your first approach? Looks good to me.

Comment: Tried using var or dynamic?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear as to what you are asking.  Are you saying that you are currently doing the first?  Is that giving you an issue?  Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Why use `Object` as the type of `element`? `Object` doesn't have `Outer` and `Inner` properties.

Comment: @Oded Because I'm not that good at C# yet. I Went with `Object` because I've create an, well..., object. And the approach is working but I've been told that it's better to use implicit iterators.

Comment: @CRMconfusee in this case, using a foreach adds complexity and decreases clarity.  Stick with your original implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the anonymous type correctly by using `var` instead for `object` in the loop. `var` infers the type, and allows you to use the anonymous object as expected.

```
IEnumerable<Type1> t1 = ...
IEnumerable<Type2> t2 = ...
var t12 = t1.Zip(t2, (outer, inner)
  => new{ Outer = outer, Inner = inner});
List<Type3> t3 = new List<Type3>();

foreach(var element in t12)
  t3.Add(new Type3(element.Outer, element.Inner));
```

If you would like to use `Tuple` you could do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> t1 = new[] { "test" };
IEnumerable<int> t2 = new[] { 1 };
IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> t3 = t1.Zip(t2, (outer, inner) => Tuple.Create(outer, inner));
```

Comment: `t12` should also be declared as `var` and not `IEnumerable<Object>`

Comment: Is there a way to say "it's a <Type1,Type2>" without actually creating a class for it?

Comment: @CRMconfusee That's an anonymous type.   You use `var` with anonymous types.

Comment: +1. `Tuple<Type1,Type2>` may be easier to understand if you are very new to anonymous types/C# as you'll be able to explicitly provide type for all variables.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I like *Tuple* better because it sets more limited bounds on the object returned. I prefer to specify that the *var* is of *Tuple<ThisOrThat>* type, if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> t1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<int> t2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var t12 = t1.Zip(t2, (outer, inner) => new { Outer = outer, Inner = inner });
var t3 = t12.Select(t => new { O = t.GetPropValue("Outer"), 
                               I = t.GetPropValue("Inner") });
```