# Linq to iterate through a collection and add another collection to its member

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I need to iterate through a collection and add another collection to one of its member using Linq.

For example I have this class

```
public class Product
{
    public string Car { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Part> Part { get; set; }
}
```

This class would be within a collection like

```
IEnumerable<Product> ProductList
```

How can I populate the `Part`-property for each `Product` using `GetPartData()` with Linq

```
private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Part>> GetPartData()
{
    return new List<List<Part>>() { 
        new List<Part>{
            new Part(){PartType="11",PartValue=1},
            new Part(){PartType="12",PartValue=2}
        },
        new List<Part>{
            new Part(){PartType="21",PartValue=1},
            new Part(){PartType="22",PartValue=2}
        }
    };
}
```

So ultimately, my `ProductList[0].Part` should be equal to `GetPartData()[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both sequences should be linked via index you can use `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
ProductList = ProductList.Zip(GetPartData()
    , (product, part) => new Product
    {
        Car = product.Car,
        Part = part
    })
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @tim-schmelter. Considering the fact that I would have a lot of properties apart from "part". Is there a better way to do it or else do I have to map each properties. How will I need to refine it if I can use Auto Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to enumerate two `IEnumerable` at a time to match items from both. The `ProductList` and the result of `GetPartData`.

```
// The two IEnumerable
var products = ProductList;
var parts = GetPartData();

foreach((product, part) in (products, parts))  // will not work :(
{
    product.Part = part;
}
```

Solutions [has been debated before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721939/how-to-iterate-through-two-ienumerables-simultaneously).

The [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method will do it.

```
// The two IEnumerable
var products = ProductList;
var parts = GetPartData();

products.Zip(parts, (product, part) => product.Part = part).ToList();
```

The `ToList()` is **really important**, to [force the execution](http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-linq-to-objects-6-deferred-execution).

If you are not comfortable with the lambda, you can do it like this:

```
// The two IEnumerable
var products = ProductList;
var parts = GetPartData();

products.Zip(parts, ProductPartAssociation).ToList();

...

Product ProductPartAssociation(Product product, IEnumerable<Part> part)
{
   product.Part = part;
   return product;      // Actually not used.
}
```

The result of the Zip is an `IEnumerable` of whatever the `ProductPartAssociation` function return. You don't care about it, because what you need is just to be sure that the `ProductPartAssociation` is executed.