# Is there a way to loop over multiple variables in a for each loop in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to loop over two string arrays but does not work.
Would probably look something like the following:

```
For Each (s1, s2) As (String, String) In (stringArray1, stringArray2)
```

Is there something similar to python tuples that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that vb.net don't support this in this way.

If you have two IEnumerables, you can do something like this

```
Using lst1 As IEnumerator(Of X) = List1.GetEnumerator(),
      lst2 As IEnumerator(Of Y) = List2.GetEnumerator()

    While lst1 .MoveNext() AndAlso lst2 .MoveNext() 
        If lst1 .Current.Equals(lst2 .Current) Then
            ''Put here your code.
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

For a better explanation, check this related link: [Is it possible to iterate over two IEnumerable objects at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981867/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-two-ienumerable-objects-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I think you've copied an answer from the link. But the linked question was slightly different: it was seeking equal entries. I think you should remove the If `If lst1 .Current.Equals(lst2 .Current) Then`

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 4 you could use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387036.aspx).

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arr1() As String = {"a", "b", "c"}
    Dim arr2() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
    For Each t In TupleSequence(arr1, arr2)
        Console.WriteLine(t.Item1 & "," & t.Item2)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
Function TupleSequence(Of T1, T2)(
    ByVal seq1 As IEnumerable(Of T1),
    ByVal seq2 As IEnumerable(Of T2)
    ) As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of T1, T2))
    Return Enumerable.Zip(seq1, seq2, 
      Function(s1, s2) Tuple.Create(s1, s2)
    )
End Function
```

Not as nice as the Python though.

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same length you could do something like...

```
dim i as integer = 0
do until i = s1.length
dim s1Value as string = s1(i)
dim s2Value as string = s2(i)
i += 1
loop
```

Answer (score -1):

I have studied the same question before, but found no beautiful way for coding in VB.Net. But I think it is not necessary do the same as in Python, Tcl, etc. So I just use a For-Loop, similar to Jack's answer. This also works for List.

```
'List1.Count = List2.Count
For i as Integer = 0 To List1.Count - 1
        'Work on List1.Item(i) and List2.Item(i)
Next
```

Comment: My guess would be that this isn`t to efficient, since in classical list each Item request would walk from list start to i element to access it. Maybe .net is built for this command to be more efficient, but this probably would be a bad practice.